# AngularJS start watch after loading content

Tags: angularjs

im new in AngularJS.
Trying create first app, and have problem.
Have list of checkboxes

```
<div class='order-box row-fluid' ng-repeat="order in orders" ng-model="orders">
   <input type="checkbox" value="{{ order.id }}" ng-model="order.selected">
<div>
```

orders is filling from server by ajax query on load page.

```
function OrdersCtrl($scope, Order){
    $scope.orders = Order.query();
    $scope.$watch('orders', function(v){
        if (!v) return;
        alert(v);
    }, true);
}
```

Primary target is calculate cost by selected checkboxes.

But on load page i see alerts, how start watch only after load content?

Second litle question:
Have ng-repeat on div. And all repeatet divs like

```
<div class="order-box row-fluid ng-scope ng-pristine ng-valid" ng-repeat="order in orders" ng-model="orders">
```

Is it normal?

Answer (score 4):

Try add a flag, or try it on jsfiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Q3hKa/5/).

```
function OrdersCtrl($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.orders = [];
    var first = true; //this doesn't belong to any scope, it will be deallocated after the current cycle.

    var ajax = function () {
        $scope.orders = [{
            id: 1,
            selected: true
        }, {
            id: 2,
            selected: true
        }, {
            id: 3,
            selected: true
        }, {
            id: 4,
            selected: true
        }];
    };

    $scope.$watch('orders', function (n, o) {
        if (first) {
            $timeout(ajax, 2000); //simulate the ajax call. Assume data comes back in 2 seconds.
        } else {
            alert(n);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I know it. But it show allert before load page 2 time (i have 10+ checkboxes, but show only 2 on start), and after click on checkbox.

Comment: maybe you can post your code on jsfiddle.net and i can take a look.

Comment: Im dont know how right paste code on fiddle, but link: http://jsfiddle.net/Q3hKa/1

Comment: Looking that, i make it =) http://jsfiddle.net/Actimele/Q3hKa/3/ but in JSfiddle, no popup on start. How watch only array, and get only 1 selected element?

Comment: In your code its reset checkboxes on 2 sec. Im understand your idea. Im update main question, can you anwer?

Comment: @Actimele $timeout(ajax, 2000) is to simulate the ajax call, not reset the checkbox.

Answer (score 2):

1. There is no way to avoid the first call; You have to use a flag to skip that one.
2. There will always be a 2nd call too. That is when the `orders` gets populated. To avoid that one, you can check if `oldVal` is an empty array.
3. I think you should watch the `selected` property; not all properties of an order.
4. The watch should compare values, not instances; hence the `true` param on `$watch`

Here is the code with a custom `watch` function:

```
// watch only order.selected
var watch = function(o) {
  var mapped = _.map(o.orders, function(o){
    return o.selected || false;
  });
  return mapped; 
};

var firstWatch = true;
$scope.$watch(watch, function(newVal, oldVal) {
  if ( firstWatch || oldVal.length === 0 ) {
      firstWatch = false;
      return;
  }
  console.log('changed', newVal, oldVal);
}, true);
```

See this example : http://plnkr.co/edit/q29mXXcdHRYHG9frvfNC?p=preview. There is nothing logged to the console until you actually check an item.

Comment: Maybe it make do with change html/model? What about repeated rows?

Comment: ReferenceError: _ is not defined

Comment: angular.isDefined(oldVal) && oldVal.length === 0 to avoid the error